# How can I refactor this if statement? (React)

Tags: reactjs

In my React app, the user can choose a background. I have a bunch of local images stored, and when the user picks a background, it's passed to function backgroundChange()

All the images are imported at the top of my component like so:

```
import book from './Images/book.jpg'
import beach from './Images/beach.jpg'
import flowers from './Images/flowers.jpg'
```

And my function code is a switch statement with logic as follows:

```
backgroundChange(chosenBg) {
  const bgContainer = document.getElementById('backgroundContainer');
        
  switch(chosenBg) {

    case 'book':
       bgContainer.style.backgroundImage = `url(${book})`
       break;

    case 'beach':
       bgContainer.style.backgroundImage = `url(${beach})`
       break;

    case 'flowers':
       bgContainer.style.backgroundImage = `url(${flowers})`
       break;
}
```

I'm a beginner and I know there must be a way to do it with one statement using a variable to get the relevant imported image and plug it into the url() statement -  e.g. `url(${flowers})` - but I just can't work out how?

Comment: if this is indeed a react app you are doing something wrong - you should (almost) never access and mutate the DOM directly

Comment: Eek… what should I be doing to change element styles as part of functions then? 

I am using components and JSX to render everything else, I just couldn’t work out how to mutate styles?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html

Answer (score 1):

You could define the respective css classes

```
.book {
  background-image: url(...)
}

.beach {
  background-image: url(...)
}

.flowers {
  background-image: url(...)
}
```

Then add a property like `backgroundClass = "beach" | "flowers" | "book"` to your component and use this property as `className` in the rendering of your component.

```
render() {
  return <div className={this.props.backgroundClass}>... </div>
}
```

And when the selection of the background changes, just update the `backgroundClass` property, and react will take care of the rest ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use state and an attribute to accomplish this

```js
class BackGrounds extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {background: "white"};
  }
  
  setBG = e => {
    this.setState({background:e.target.getAttribute("background")});
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <div>
          <div background="blue" onClick={this.setBG}>Donor1</div>
          <div background="yellow" onClick={this.setBG}>Donor2</div>
          <div background="black" onClick={this.setBG}>Donor3</div>
        </div>
        <div style={{backGroundColor:this.state.background}}> Background Receptor </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Embed the values in attribute of the element to be clicked, update the props when clicked to contain the desired background. Note that this is a starter code just to help you preview how to handle things like this. You need to extend this code to work according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

```js
export default function YourComponent() {

    const [bg, setBg] = useState(book); //initial value;

    const backgroundChange = (chosenBg) => {
        switch (chosenBg) {
            case 'book':
                setBg(book)
                break;

            case 'beach':
                setBg(beach)
                break;
        
            default:
                setBg(flowers)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div style={{background: `url(${bg})`}}>
            <button onClick={()=>backgroundChange('book')}>Image 1</button>
            <button onClick={()=>backgroundChange('beach')}>Image 2</button>
            <button onClick={()=>backgroundChange('flowers')}>Image 3</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Albeit you can use query selectors, you don't need them with React. I'd would simply use styled-components and pass it the `chosenBg` prop.

```js
import styled from "styled-components" 

const BackgroundContainer = styled.div`
  background-image: ${({chosenBg})=> getBackground(chosenBg)};
  background-size: cover;
`

function getBackground(chosenBg) {
  if("book") return `url(${book})`
  if("beach") return `url(${beach})`
  return `url(${flowers})`
}

function MyComponent (chosenBg){
  return (
    <BackrgoundContainer chosenBg={chosenBg}>
      stuff
    </BackgroundContainer>
  )
 }
```